# iOS: Can't minimize the keyboard after user types in TextView (xcode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

Another user provided me with the following code in order to make a mini toolbar above the keyboard when a user is typing in a specific TextView. All I need is a little "close" button to minimize the keyboard when the user is finished, so he/she can continue manipulating the app.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad]
UIToolbar *inputAccessoryView = [[UIToolbar alloc]init]; // Create one input accessory view, tool bar will be easy for you  
inputAccessoryView.frame = CGRectMake(0,self.view.frame.size.height - 44, self.view.frame.size.width, 44);

// Add required buttons
UIBarButtonItem *fontItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Font"
                                                             style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                            target:self action:@selector(changeFont:)];
UIBarButtonItem *removeItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Remove"
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                              target:self action:@selector(removeTextView:)];
//Use this to put space in between your toolbox buttons
UIBarButtonItem *flexItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                          target:nil
                                                                          action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *doneItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                             style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                                            target:self action:@selector(dismissKeyBoard:)];

NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:fontItem,removeItem,flexItem,doneItem, nil];
[inputAccessoryView setItems:items animated:YES];

//You should create an outlet for the text view before doing this 
[self.questionsTextView setInputAccessoryView:inputAccessoryView];
```

}

However, the app crashes whenever the "close" button is pressed. I'm not sure if I am following the direction correctly: I am supposed to make an outlet for the TextView, so I made the output to the viewController's header file and named it questionsTextView. Then I synthesized it in my .m file, and named the instance _questionsTextView.

Can anyone please give me hand? I'm brand-new to xcode and am slowly getting the hang of objective-c! Thanks.

Comment: Did you implement all of the button action methods? You need to implement `dismissKeyBoard:` and `removeTextView:` and `changeFont:`.

Comment: And they need to have *exactly* that capitalization and *exactly* that number of parameters (one).

Comment: Oh, by the way, always include the crash message. It would tell us which method you forgot to implement!

Comment: Can you please tell me how and where to implement them? Here is the crash message:   HealthTry2[42902:907] -[ThirdViewController dismissKeyBoard:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ed6dac0 2013-05-07 12:47:29.206 ExampleApp[42902:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ThirdViewController dismissKeyBoard:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ed6dac0' *** First throw call stack: libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error message you supplied suggest there something wrong with your methods.

```
@selector(changeFont:)]
@selector(removeTextView:)];
@selector(dismissKeyBoard:)];
```

double check the all three methods take a parameter as : symbol specify it should, and also check your method spelling.

verify object can respond to method:

NSLog(@"Method does respond: %d", [self respondsToSelector:@selector(aMethod)]);

Comment: Actually, I just realized that I never implemented those methods! Can you please provide me the code how to implement them?

Comment: @jake9115 Seriously?  It's your project, so how should we know how they are implemented?

Comment: I thought they would just be implemented with something like -(void)dismissKeyBoard{  [myTextView resignFirstResponder];  }   but that didn't work

Comment: // **NOTE these method do not take a parameter so remove : symbol from selector 

-(void)changeFont { 
    [self.textView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:12.0]];
}


-(void)dismissKeyBoard {
    [self.textView resignFirstResponder];
}

-(void)removeTextView {
     [self.textView removeFromSuperview];
}

Comment: That made all the difference! Thanks!!